# file upload a pdf in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi everyone i need some help i work a program called file upload , but i dont get it what happen to the file i upload in laravel. in public folder there's a name called php4CA1.tmp every time i upload a pdf file please can anybody help me ? what is the meaning of this php4CA1.tmp or my code is wrong?

```
    $request->validate([
        'cover' => 'required',
        'book' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);

    $image = $request->file('cover');
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('images'),$new_name);

    $book = $request->file('book');
    $new_book_name = rand() . '.' . $book->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $book->move(public_path('books'),$book);

    $data = array(
        'cover' => $new_name,
        'book' => $new_book_name,
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'price' => $request->price
    );
    Book::create($data);
```

[image: Here is the file upload in laravel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing $book in

> $book->move(public_path('books'),$book);

Use this:

```
$book = $request->file('book');
$new_book_name = rand() . '.' . $book->getClientOriginalExtension();
$book->move(public_path('books'),$new_book_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi friend please follow as below you are passing the file instead of file name,

```
$book = $request->file('book');
$new_book_name = rand() . '.' . $book->getClientOriginalExtension();
$response = $book->move(public_path('books'),$new_book_name );
```